How to Prevent Subsystems from Responding to Events from Other Game States
I'm writing a game from scratch in C++, using the book Game Coding Complete as a guide.  The engine in the book has an event manager which is used to communicate between the game's systems, such as syncing the transformations of objects in the physics system and the scene graph.  A system can register an event listener that listens for a specific type of event and then runs a callback function if the event manager receives an event of that type.
I didn't like how the book handled state management, however, so I added a state-management system based on this article.  In my implementation, states represent game modes, with each state containing its own actors, physics system, player views, etc.
The original code uses events to alert systems when an actor that needs to be managed by that system has been initialized.  For instance, the scene graph listens for when visible actor is created so that it can add a scene node for the actor. The problem is the engine described in Game Coding Complete assumes there's only one instance of systems such as the scene graph or physics manager.  In my state-pattern system there are theoretically multiple scene graphs, physics managers, and so on.  So if I have two states that each possess a scene graph, when state A initializes a visible actor both the scene graph in state A and state B will hear the event and add a node to render the actor, even though the actor isn't a part of state B.
Keep in mind that systems do not know which state they are a part of.  Moreover, some subsystems are separated from the game state by layers of abstraction, meaning the game state doesn’t have direct access to them either.  For instance, the scene graph is an implementation of a base class called ScreenElement which is in turn managed by a view management class.
How do I communicate that an actor has been created to only the systems of the state that actor belongs to while keeping my engine loosely coupled?  Alternatively, what's a good way of identifying that the actor being created is or isn't in the same state as the subsystem receiving the notification?  What are the best practices for this sort of problem?

"Keep in mind that systems do not know which state they are a part of." Then something has to know. Can you have two states active at once? If not, it can be as easy as "stopping to listen" to an event once a state is no longer active, and reactivate the listener once the state becomes active again. In addition, you could link events to states, and have all the events go through the state event handler before being transferred to the sub-system (so subsystem registers to parent/owner (which is the state), and the the state registers to the main event queue).

Thanks for your response.  For the time being, I’ve settled on turning off the event listeners for inactive states.  My current project is small enough for that to work.  I’ll keep your other suggestion in mind if I need to expand the functionality to allow for actors to be created in inactive scenes.
